# jsdoc2md: how to sort function when using multiple files?

Tags: jsdoc2md

I am using jsdoc2md to generate the readme.MD based on multiple files : 
jsdoc2md  --files a.js b.js > README.md

The result provides a list of unsorted functions.
How to get the list of all function from all files in alphabetic order ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could use [jsdoc2md.getTemplateData()](https://github.com/jsdoc2md/jsdoc-to-markdown/blob/master/docs/API.md#jsdoc2mdgettemplatedataoptions--promise) to fetch the data, sort it as required, then pass it into [jsdoc2md.render()](https://github.com/jsdoc2md/jsdoc-to-markdown/blob/master/docs/API.md#jsdoc2mdrenderoptions--promise) as the `options.data`..